# Secure websocket with custom domain to OpenShift app failed

Tags: security, ssl, websocket, openshift

I added a custom domain and custom certificate to my app.It seems that **custom certificate is not provided when wss try to connect**.
I tested http connection like https:// api.myapp.com, every thing is ok.
But if I try websocket like wss://api.myapp.com:8443, every thing is not ok.

chrome says:

```
failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled
```

a test tool github.com/wtmmac/websocket-tester says:

```
websocket.Dial wss://api.myapp.com:8443: x509: certificate is valid for *.rhcloud.com, rhcloud.com, not api.myapp.com
```

Is there some additional configs needed after alias-update-cert, if want to use secure websocket with custom domain?

Comment: Have you checked: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-domains-ssl.html ?

Comment: I did not do step 'Generating a CSR', i just followed startssl steps to create Certificate. Openshift alias settings show this:"SSL Certificate
added tue, october 20th 2015"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenShift Online does not currently support the ability to use a Custom SSL Certificate with secure web sockets.  If you would like to use wss I would suggest that you use the app-domain.rhcloud.com address that is provided for you by OpenShift.

Comment: Thank! Seems there is no other way.